# Mailkit adding a line-break in the Sender header of the email

Tags: c#, mailkit, mimekit

While using Mailkit, I have noticed that it adds a line break if the email address is lengthy. For example, take the set of headers below

```
Sender: Paranoid Human 
<aaatest123.bbbbb.com@dddded32.large.Syberuuusoluppppp.com>
```

The source code I use for setting it is as follows.

```
 message.Sender = new MailboxAddress("Paranoid Human","aaatest123.bbbbb.com@dddded32.large.Syberuuusoluppppp.com");
```

Is there a way I can fix this?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to "fix" this because it isn't broken :)

The specifications specify that header values should be folded if they are long and that is what you are seeing.

This is not a problem because receiving clients will unfold the headers.

Comment: Thanks, was debating this with a Unix admin and wanted to be sure.
Thanks again for Mailkit, it is everything Easymail should be and more!